# How to increase the hover width of a dropdown item

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, drop-down-menu, hover

I have a dropdown menu inside bootstrap nav tabs. But a particular dropdown item only hovers for a limited width.

the code snippet :

```
<ul class="page-title__nav common-list nav nav-tabs">
     <li class="dropdown">
         <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Inventory<b class="caret"></b></a>
               <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                   <li style="margin-left: 15px;"><a data-toggle="tab" onclick="loadCategories()">Categories</a></li><br>
                   <li><a data-toggle="tab" onclick="loadItems()">Items</a></li><br>
                   <li><a data-toggle="tab" onclick="loadModifierGroups()">Modifier Groups</a></li><br>
               </ul>
      </li>                 
</ul>
```

The view :

[image: the view]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to remove style="margin-left: 15px;" from you first element

Comment: yes. it dint work, it only gives margin from the left side

Answer (score 0):

ok try this

```
<ul class="page-title__nav common-list nav nav-tabs">
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Inventory<b class="caret"></b></a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a data-toggle="tab" onclick="loadCategories()">Categories</a>
        <a data-toggle="tab" onclick="loadItems()">Items</a>
        <a data-toggle="tab" onclick="loadModifierGroups()">Modifier Groups</a>
    </div>
</li>
</ul>
```